# Being and Was, Which one is correct and why?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs, linking-verbs

Can you please tell me which sentence is correct here? What if I just take out the preposition "with", is it still grammatically correct?

> Less coal was burned in 1980, **with** its figure **being** just over 15 billion units.
>
> Less coal was burned in 1980, **with** its figure **was** just over 15 billion units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Being," if this is one sentence.

> Less coal was burned in 1980, with its figure being just over 15 billion units.
>
> Less coal was burned in 1980, its figure being just over 15 billion units.

The latter case seems a bit questionable to me.  I'd be more likely to use a dash than a comma here.  That's kind of my style, though.

If you omit "with," then you may need something stronger than a comma as the two parts of the sentence are no longer strongly linked.  If you split it into two sentences (or strongly, using a semicolon), you should use "was."

> Less coal was burned in 1980. Its figure was just over 15 billion units.
>
> Less coal was burned in 1980; its figure was just over 15 billion units.

Comment: THank you for the clear advice, I will note that @farncy. By the way, I don't know what time it is in your country, but have a nice day!